# 'MyObject[]' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor to use it as parameter 'T'

Tags: c#, generics

In MyRequest class I have:

```
public static T RetrieveData<T>(Uri uri) where T : class, new()
{
        return requestData<T>(query);
}
```

The Uri returns an array of strings such as:

```
{

 "prop1": "JOHN",
 "prop2": "JULIE",
 "value": 9

}, 
{

 "prop1": "KATE",
 "prop2": "Ryan",
 "value": 8

}
```

This is how I call my method:

```
var obj = MyRequest.RetrieveData<MyObject[]>("http://.....");
```

This is how MyObject is defined:

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public string prop1;
        public string prop2; 
        public double value; 
    }
```

And this is the error I get:

> MyObject[]' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyRequest.RetrieveData(uri)'

I got the method to work just fine when I tweak the uri to return just an array of 1 element and call it:

```
var obj = MyRequest.RetrieveData<MyObject>("http://.....");
```

instead of

```
MyObject[]
```

but I really need to use an array.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `List<MyObject>` instead? Unfortunately there's not enough information here to answer fully.

Comment: Like a charm! Thank you very much. May add it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens becase type T[] is **fixed size** array and doesn't have parameterless constructor. It is obvious that fixed size array **require this size**. For example:

```
var foo = new bar[0];
var foo = new bar[123];
var foo = new bar[count];
```

You can't initialize something like this:

```
var foo = new bar[]();
var foo = new bar[];
```

So it is clear that new() quantifier can't be used with fixed size arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should try deserialising to `List<T>` instead of an array as your JSON library (likely JSON.Net, but hard to guess from your code) requires the type to have a constructor. For example:

```
var obj = MyRequest.RetrieveData<List<MyObject>>("http://.....");
```